# Powershell скрипт не видит TeamCity переменных

Tags: powershell, teamcity

При выборе Source code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS-скрипт выполняется.

При выборе выполнения из файла того же скрипта, но только помещенного в файл и расположенного в VCS

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

возникает ошибка, а именно не видит переменные %teamcity.build.branch%, %build.vcs.number%.

Пробую добавить 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но это ни к чему не приводит.

Благодарю, за любую помощь.

Comment: потому что это переменные конфигурации. вы запускайте файл, который выполняется. который ищет переменные окружения, которых нет. задайте переменные окружения, привойте им значения конфиг. переменных

Comment: @SeniorAutomator, Спасибо! В который раз помогаете. Может оформите, как ответ, чтобы я мог его принять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что это переменные конфигурации. Они не видеы из окружения.

вы запускайте файл, который выполняется, который ищет переменные окружения %teamcity.*%, которых нет. Задайте переменные окружения, присвойте им значения конфиг. переменных

```
%env.myVar% = %teamcity.*%
```

Используйте их в скрипте

Comment: Вот так правильнее по идее:
'$BuildCounter     = $env:Build_Counter'

По крайней мере я так тяну. )